# More than one form on a single page

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

My image upload form on my profile edit page isn't working. The two forms must be separate as they work independently. The image upload script uploads the image before the profile edit form is submitted.

I tested the image upload on a separate page where it was the only thing on the page and it worked. So I am assuming it is the other form that is messing it up. The two forms are acting on different scripts and both methods are posts.

Here is the jscript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageupload/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageupload/scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() { 
        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="imageupload/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."//>');
        $("#cropimage").ajaxForm({ target: '#preview' }).submit();
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Here's the form;

```
<form id="cropimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../imageupload/ajaximage.php">
  <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" class="filebutton"/><br>
</form>
```

Here is the other form. Its a long one;

```
    echo '<form action="phpscripts/artistupdate.php" method="post" id="profileedit"><input type="text" name="artistname" value="'. $row['artistname'].'" class="name"     maxlength="80"><span id="editlink"><t1>Your profile link will be: <br><a     href="http://newbornsounds.co.uk/artists/artist.php?artist='.$row['artistname'].'">    <b>http://newbornsounds.co.uk/artists/artist.php?artist=<FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">'.$row['artistname'].'</font></b></a></span><br><div id="urlwarn"><t1>Please note that if you change your url all the links you have placed outside of NBS will be affected.</t1></div>';
  }
}
?>
<hr>
<?php 
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $pass = $_SESSION['password']; 
  include ("../database.php");
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' AND     password='$pass' AND artist='Y'");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div id="artistsbio"><textarea name="bio" rows="10" cols="80" name="bio" value="'.     $row['bio']. '" class="bio">'. $row['bio']. '</textarea><br><div id="probwarn"><t1>Everything is still in the beta stage so there are bound to be a few problems. If you spot one please <a     href="mailto:artists@newbornsounds.co.uk"><b>tell us about it.</b></a></t1></div>';
  }
?>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Done" class="button"></form>
```

Comment: What does the complete html of the forms look like? You cannot nest forms.

Comment: where is the other form?

Comment: make sure you have two submit buttons for each of your form

Comment: Do you expect both forms to execute at once or only the one the user indicates?

Comment: Only the forms the user submits should be submitted. The are independent from eachother. And the upload image form submits with javascript when a file is selected

Comment: I have added the code for the other form. I know this code is a bit strange but its the only way i could get that one to work.

Comment: New development. It works when a submit button is added to the image form. This probably means that its something to do with the javascript

Comment: Just as an aside, you can definitely write cleaner code, and it will make your life much easier. You don't need to be echoing html wholesale: just close your php and write it, so it's readable to you, and then open the php tag again to complete the code section.

Comment: Yeah i know I can. Its force of habit really. I only started learning php about a week ago and only found out you could do that really recently. I have started to change my ways

Comment: It seems to me that the javascript isnt calling the php file when another form is on the page. I know nothing about javascript so any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no submit button in your cropimage form, which might be the pb.
If I understand well, you want it to be submitted when there is a change in the photoimg field, without submit button.

Try [Submitting a form by pressing enter without a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477691/html-submitting-a-form-by-pressing-enter-without-a-submit-button)
(displaying a submit button outside the screen if you don't want to display it).

BTW, jquery live is deprecated.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have figured it out now. Turns out the javascript in my memberstoolbar was messing around with the javascript line that was submitting the form. But thanks for saying the .live function is deprecated. Didn't realise

Comment: Strange, i switched the live to on but it no longer works with on. Whats happening?